# Magento 2.4.5 Missing exchange field error after Upgrade

Tags: message-queue, rabbit-mq, magento2-4-5

After upgrading from 2.4.4 to 2.4.5 I am seeing the following error in admin when I try and save a product :

```
Missing exchange field for publisher product_action_attribute.update in connection config. Missing exchange field for publisher product_action_attribute.website.update in connection config. Missing exchange field for publisher media.storage.catalog.image.resize in connection config. Missing exchange field for publisher inventory.source.items.cleanup in connection config. Missing exchange field for publisher inventory.mass.update in connection config. Missing exchange field for publisher inventory.reservations.update in connection config. Missing exchange field for publisher inventory.reservations.cleanup in connection config.
```

I think this appears to be a problem with message queue configuration - how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Magento 2.4.5 ensure that publishers in the message queue config also have an exchange entry under the db section

```
        'product_action_attribute.update' => [
            'connections' => [
                'amqp' => [
                    'name' => 'amqp',
                    'exchange' => 'magento',
                    'disabled' => false
                ],
                'db' => [
                    'name' => 'db',
                    'exchange' => 'magento',
                    'disabled' => true
                ]
            ]
        ],
```